# ruby delete command misbehaving?

Tags: ruby

Manipulating an array of integers is returning unexpected results with `ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin13]` :

```
a = [1, 126, 158, 201, 102]
=> [1, 126, 158, 201, 102]
b = 102
=> 102
a.delete(b)
=> 102
```

many slight variations of syntax always lead to the same result.

is the syntax mistaken, could there be some higher command that negates this command or worse, is some corruption issue at hand?  How can this be ascerted?

Comment: What's your expected behavior/result?

Comment: I don't see any unexpected results. Can you explain, *precisely*, what result you are expecting, why you are expecting that result, and how your expected result differs from the observed result? From everything you posted, it seems that everything is behaving exactly as it should, and exactly as documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete) docs:

> When no block is given, removes from self each element ele such that
> ele == obj; returns the last deleted element...

In your case `b` is equal to 102, hence it prints its value after defining the variable. Then `a.delete(b)` corroborates that there's an element in `a` equals to `b` so it deletes it and returns the value of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

What were you expecting to see as a result?  The snippet you show seems to be working exactly as expected.

Examine the contents of a immediately after executing your code shown above - you should find that the final entry has been deleted.

The delete() method is perhaps defined in a slightly surprising way for Ruby.  One might expect it to return the modified array and leave the original unchanged so that one could use it like this:

`a.delete(b).delete(158)`

and then for there to be a bang version which modifies the array in place:

`a.delete!(b)`

but that's not the way it's been defined.  The basic delete() method modifies the array on which it's called.